# Creating a file with FileStream returns an InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, serialization, filestream

It returns the `exception` specifically at `line 12`.

```
    public void saveToXML()
    {
        URL newURL = new URL();
        newURL.type = type;
        newURL.name = name;
        newURL.info = info;
        newURL.url = url;
        newURL.isProtected = isProtected;
        newURL.amountOfClicks = amountOfClicks;
        XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(URL));
        string directory = @"C:\Users\PC-User\Documents\Link" + newURL.name + ".xml";
        using (var file = File.Create(directory))
        {
            xml.Serialize(file, url);
        }
    }
```

More details in exception message if needed:

> Synchronous operations should not be performed on the UI thread.  Consider wrapping this method in Task.Run.

Thanks!

Comment: if there is an error log, you should post it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider something like this? :

```
public async Task saveToXml(){
    string directory = @"C:\Users\PC-User\Documents\Link" + newURL.name + ".xml";
    await Task.Run(()=>
    {
        Task.Yield();
        using (var file = File.Create(directory))
        {
            xml.Serialize(file, url);
        }
    });
}
```