# Save data with a button in C# XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I want to program a little local database.  I have a form written which has different TextBlocks.  After I have entered text into the blocks, I will press a button to save the data to a text file.

So I tried it with the following code:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string x = textBox.Text;
    string p = "J:\\test.txt";
    File.WriteAllText(p, x);
}
```

Now my problem is that everytime VS2015 writes an error back:
Synchronous operations should not be performed on the UI thread
So I tried this:

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string x = textBox.Text;
    string p = "J:\\test.txt";
    await WriteTextAsync(p,x);
}

private async Task WriteTextAsync(string filePath, string text)
{
    byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

    using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
        FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None,
        bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
    {
        await sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
    };
}
```

But this also doesn't work. Can somebody help me?

Comment: What kind of application you're working for? WPF? UWP?

Comment: "Also doesn't work" is very vague.   What happens when you use the second set of posted code?

Comment: maybe helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31769505/ccreating-a-file-with-filestream-returns-an-invalidoperationexception

Comment: What kind of application you're working for? WPF? UWP? : Im working on UWP

"Also doesn't work" is very vague. What happens when you use the second set of posted code?:
The same Failure appear.Synchronous operations should not be performed on the UI thread. Consider wrapping this method in Task.Run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going down the async/await route as you are - I would simply change your choice of File.WriteAllText to a StreamWriter:

```
    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string x = textBox.Text;
        string p = "J:\\test.txt";
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(p, FileMode.Append))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            await sw.WriteLineAsync(x);
    }
```

Give that a go and see if you get different results

You can also follow the suggestion of wrapping  with Task.Run and then go back to your original method

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string x = textBox.Text;
        string p = "C:\\test.txt";
        Task.Run(() => File.WriteAllText(p, x));
    }
```

Comment: Thx for your fast Reply, but now I have another Problem:
Its not possible to convert "string" into "System.IO.Stream"

Comment: I have edited my answer to feed StreamWriter a FileStream rather than the string path.  Change the FileMode to whichever mode suits your needs.

Comment: again the same failure:
Synchronous operations should not be performed on the UI thread.  Consider wrapping this method in Task.Run.

Comment: I have updated to include how to wrap with Task.Run as suggested.

Comment: Now another Error Occur: An Interface,which is for another Thread marshalled was called by the programm.  (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))
I´m sry for so much questions.

Comment: I think you need to do some dispatching.  I am not able to UWP where I am - but this question and answer may help you.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/253f1e74-6f75-4ce6-8aae-4f899a30c9d8/the-application-called-an-interface-that-was-marshalled-for-a-different-thread-exception-from?forum=winappswithcsharp